# Updating a global variable within a function multiple times in Python

Tags: python, function, variables, global

Essentially I'm trying to update a string which I declare at the beginning.  I then pass a list through a function which, after passing a test, will add the item from the list to the string, separating each item with a semi-colon.

This is an abridged version of what I'm doing but it demonstrates the issue I believe.

```
import os

passList=""

def checkItem(inString):
    if inString.endswith(".tif")==True:
        if passList=="":
            passList=inString
        else:
            passList=passList + ";" + inString

itemList=os.listdir("C:\\temp")

for item in itemList:
    checkItem(item)

print(passList)
```

I checked some documentation about using the 'global' function but they don't seem to show examples that apply to my situation.  Currently I'm getting the 'function used before declaring' error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the entire error log

Comment: You really don't want global mutable state at all. It's a bad idea.

Comment: Despite reading all that documentation, you don't seem to have used the global statement at all. Use it inside the function, the error will go away.

Comment: Adding `global passList` as @HasanRamezani suggests will be needed, you also have the problem that the script doesn't produce a ` 'function used before declaring' ` error. That error just means that you are calling the function above the place in the code where you actually implement it. And that's not happening in your example.You aren't running the same script you've shown us.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
def checkItem(inString):
    global passList
    # rest of function code
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Hasan Ramezani's answer will fix your error. But consider refactoring to remove the need for it.

```
import os

itemList=filter(lambda x: x.endswith(".tif"), os.listdir("C:\\temp"))
itemList=";".join(itemList)

print(itemList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both Hasan and Clint provided with excellent answers.

Because of the complexity of the actual code (can't post here) I ended up declaring 'global' for the 'passList' variable both at the start and within the function.

```
import os

global passList
passList=""

def checkItem(inString):
    if inString.endswith(".tif")==True:
        global passList
        if passList=="":
            passList=inString
        else:
            passList=passList + ";" + inString

itemList=os.listdir("C:\\temp")

for item in itemList:
    checkItem(item)

print(passList)
```

It may not look as sexy as it could be but it works.

Thankyou so much!